# How to check spotheight in closed polyline contour data using ModelBuilder or ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile, modelbuilder, geoprocessing

I'm new in using ModelBuilder or Python script. So, i have a set of contour data and a good contour data should contain a spotheight* in every closed polyline contour data.

Is there any solution to check that every closed polyline of contour data should contain spotheight which also have same elevation or above.

[image: a correct spotheight, the elevation value also above contour]

[image: there is no spotheight and how to check this?]

*) spotheight is a point that located in closed polyline contour data which show the elevation value

Comment: In the old days we had things called *hypsometric areas* which could be intersected with points.. I used to make them in ArcInfo with AML... those were the days. Did you make the contours yourself? Is the raster still lying around? The only way I can think to do this is with ArcObjects - create a polygon of each closed contour and find the ones that don't contain another line (i.e. isolations) then look for a spot height within. Do you have any C# or VB.net ability? You could do similar in python, but it would take *for ever* to run but not model builder.

Comment: @Maundri, could you please describe the business rules for that? Should every closed polyline contain a point? etc. I am tempted to convert polylines to polygons and then just use any point-in-polygon algorithm (Spatial Join GP tool would do that, output: polygon layer with the count field where it will be stored how many points were located within the polygon; those that have 0 are those you are looking for) but I guess this is just too simple and might not work for your business rules.

Comment: we create contour from the DTM data. Actually i want to check in every closed polyline contour data should contain spotheight that represent the elevation value in that contour. just like on my first image, only the highest contour in some area that contain spotheight within it.

Comment: Sorry I know this is old, but I am curious. Did you want every level of contour to have a spot height or only the highest contour levels?

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this task, the overall work flow will be converting your lines to polygons. The `FeatureToPolygon` tool will only convert closed lines, so this will work well for limiting the lines you are working with. Next you'll want to remove all donut polygons from your analysis, which can be done with a cursor, checking if each geometry is multipart. You can then use a variety of selections to find the lines with the issues describe. Say you have a line feature like the one below:
[image]

Notice I have the field `Point_Check`. This field will be populated with information through the code below.

Code:

```
##----Locals

#Contour feature class
inLineFC = r"C:\temp\Workspace.gdb\testlines"
#Contour Elevation Field
inElevFld = "Elevation"
#Contour Check results field
checkFld = "Point_Check"

#Point feature class
pntFc = r"C:\temp\Workspace.gdb\TestPoint"
#Point elevation field
pntElevFld = "Elevation"

#Workspace GDB
workspaceGDB = r"C:\temp\Workspace.gdb"

#----End locals

from arcpy import *
import os

env.overwriteOutput = True

garbage = []

#feature to polygon
print "converting lines to polygons"
polygonFC = os.path.join (workspaceGDB,
                          "tempPolys")

FeatureToPolygon_management (inLineFC,
                             polygonFC)

garbage += [polygonFC]

#Field map to limit spatial join fields
fms = FieldMappings()
fm_elev = FieldMap()
fm_elev.addInputField (inLineFC, inElevFld)
fms.addFieldMap(fm_elev)

print "adding elevation to polygons"
#Join spatially to transfer elevation field to polygon fc
spatialJoinFC = os.path.join (workspaceGDB, "spatialJoin")
SpatialJoin_analysis (polygonFC,
                      inLineFC,
                      spatialJoinFC,
                      field_mapping = fms)
garbage += [spatialJoinFC]

#Make feature layers of points, lines, polygons
#Allows selection
print "creating feature layers"
MakeFeatureLayer_management (pntFc, "pntLyr")
MakeFeatureLayer_management (spatialJoinFC, "polyLyr")
MakeFeatureLayer_management (inLineFC, "lineLyr")

garbage += ["pntLyr", "polyLyr", "lineLyr"]

#Get polygon OID field
oidFld = Describe ("polyLyr").OIDFieldName

#Remove donuts from polygon feature class
print "removing donuts"
cursor = da.SearchCursor ("polyLyr", ["SHAPE@", "OID@"])
for row in cursor:
    #Check if feature is donut
    if not row[0].isMultipart:
        continue

    sql = '{0} = {1}'.format (AddFieldDelimiters
                              ("polyLyr", oidFld),
                              row[1])
    SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("polyLyr", "ADD_TO_SELECTION", sql)
del cursor
#If polygons are selected, delete
if Describe ("polyLyr").FIDSet:
    DeleteFeatures_management ("polyLyr")

#Determine polygons without points
SelectLayerByLocation_management ("polyLyr", "", "pntLyr")
#Switch selection - so that polygons not intersecting points are selected
SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("polyLyr", "SWITCH_SELECTION")
#Check for selection
if Describe ("polyLyr").FIDSet:
    #Select lines intersecting selected polygons
    SelectLayerByLocation_management ("lineLyr", "SHARE_A_LINE_SEGMENT_WITH", "polyLyr")
    CalculateField_management ("lineLyr", checkFld, '"NO_POINT"')


#Clear line selection
SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lineLyr", "CLEAR_SELECTION")

#iterate points
#Check all selected polygons have values greater than point value
print "iterating points"
cursor = da.SearchCursor ("pntLyr", [pntElevFld, "SHAPE@"])
for row in cursor:
    elevation = row[0]
    #Select intersecting polygons
    SelectLayerByLocation_management ("polyLyr", "", row[1])
    #Check for selection, continue if no selection
    if not Describe ("polyLyr").FIDSet:
        continue
    #iterate polygons, check values
    polyCursor = da.SearchCursor ("polyLyr", [inElevFld, "OID@"])
    for pRow in polyCursor:
        #check if polygon elevation is greater than point elevation
        polyElev = pRow[0]
        if polyElev > elevation:
            #Select polygon with improper value
            sql = '{0} = {1}'.format (AddFieldDelimiters
                                      ("polyLyr", oidFld),
                                      pRow[1])
            SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("polyLyr", "", sql)
            #Add lines to selection
            SelectLayerByLocation_management ("lineLyr",
                                              "SHARE_A_LINE_SEGMENT_WITH",
                                              "polyLyr",
                                              "", "ADD_TO_SELECTION")
    del polyCursor
del cursor

#Check if selection in line layer
if Describe ("lineLyr").FIDSet:
    print "updating lines with elevation value errors"
    CalculateField_management ("lineLyr", checkFld, '"VALUE_ERROR"')

#Clean Up
for trash in garbage:
    Delete_management (trash)

print "done"
```

Results:

[image]